How to styling AutoComplete component in Primevue
i need to how to styling AutoComplete component in PrimeVue
this is the current code sample  <AutoComplete size="small" v-model="selectedEmployee" class="" placeholder="Name or Employee ID" :suggestions="filterEmployee" @complete="search" optionLabel="name" forceSelection /> i tried add class and inline style but its not work, can't change width or color

To style the AutoComplete component in PrimeVue, you need to understand that PrimeVue uses its internal css classes for styling, which sometimes override custom styles if not applied correctly.
Solution:
We can apply using class like Add your custom class to the CLASS prop and define your style in the css file.
or
We can use inline style for width or color we use the style prop directly
